# dynamic code PhP is there a better way

Tags: php, angularjs, dynamic

Hi I was looking at migrating code to Angular or React for the view on a web application. (I am still looking at doing the former) While asking about this a developer suggested the code I was using for php was "not serious code or even semi serious!" I have no idea what he meant because he did not come back on the comment.  But now it got me think is there a better way to do this?
This is the code snippet in question, it is used on a function.php for dynamic content before being rendered on a request.php?= page.

Is there a better way of formatting this?

```
case "foo":
    if($type == "foo"){
    $sql1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM  `him_form_fields` WHERE `form_id` = '$form_id' AND `inputtype` = '$type' ORDER BY `orderby` ASC ", ARRAY_A);
        foreach($sql1 as $row1) {
            $website=get_field_value($serialno,$form_id,$row1['systemname']);
            if(!empty($website)){
                echo '<div class="foo"><a href="'.$website.'" id="pearl_per_link_a" target="_blank"><span class="foo"></span></a><input type="hidden" name="foo[]" value="'.$website.'"></div>';
            }
        }
    }
break;
```

Comment: Perhaps lack of MVC separation, perhaps lack of error handling, perhaps simple readability issues

Comment: Other potential problems: direct injection of values in SQL query, `$type` datatype ignored in comparison (so if `$type` is `0` it will match), no comments to explain what/why the code is doing what it does

Comment: There's a lot wrong just with these few lines of code

Comment: Ok I can see from the comments there is a lot wrong! "Thanks guys for comments" The code is a snippet. What this code does is get a link from d/b then the link is echoed out on a php/html5 template. along with other links and images. I understand this is not correct so I will have to get my head down and work out how to.

Comment: Actually Mark is there a better way?